# How do I specify generic type anotations in Elm?

Tags: generics, types, annotations, record, elm

Does elm have a "generics" system?
For example I have a function say `setTime`  that takes a record and changes the `.date` to the current time.
Now, if I have multiple records with a `.date` how can I use the same function on multiple different records?
I tried setting the signature to `a -> a`  but then I get the error

```
Your type annotation uses type variable `a` which means ANY type of value
can flow through, but your code is saying it specifically wants a record. Maybe
change your type annotation to be more specific?
```

Can I just make the type annotation require a record with a `.date` , if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write:

```
setTime : Date -> { a | date : Date } -> { a | date : Date }
```

Where `{ a | data : Date }` is saying any value that is a [`record`](https://elm-lang.org/docs/records) with a field named date whose type is `Date`.

---

If you use it a lot and want to avoid some tedium, you could also wrap that partial record in a type alias

```
type alias Dated a = { a | date : Date }
setTime : Date -> Dated a -> Dated a
```

And also, you could chain those

```
type alias Dated a = { a | date : Date }
type alias Checked a { a | check : Bool }
checkAtTime : Date -> Dated (Checked a) -> Dated (Checked a)
```